# Variable Height Panel with Scrollable Content and Fixed Footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing an app with a `grid` layout with 4 panels. I want to display information in one panel that can scroll `overflow` if the content begins to exceed the panel. I want to accomplish this without using a `max-height` property on the `panel-content-scrollable` div because the height of the panel varies depending on screen size etc. I would like to avoid making media queries to set a max height or something like that.

Summary of Goals:

- Scrollable Content Panel without `max-height` or a variable calculation
- Flex box end position footer with button

Below is a rough design. I have a working code snippet with my current progress using some flex box positioning and overflow but with the `max-height` property set to `550px`.

I wanted to try to use `max-height` with a `calc()` function but dont quite understand cascading of the heights and how to select the parent `panel-1`. I also tried using the max view height to calc a `max-height` but that didnt really work as I wanted it to (`calc(100vh - 50%)`).

Any insights or corrections to my thought process are much appreciated.

[image: Layout]

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  padding: 16px;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 16px;
  grid-row-gap: 16px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel-1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 12 / 6;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.panel-2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 6 / 12 / 17;
  background-color: #333;
}

.panel-3 {
  grid-area: 12 / 13 / 17 / 17;
  background-color: #333;
}

.panel-4 {
  grid-area: 12 / 1 / 17 / 13;
  background-color: #666;
}

.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #999;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.panel-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: blue;
}

.panel-content-header {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}

.panel-content-scrollable {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden scroll;
  max-height: 550px;
  background-color: #888;
}

.panel-footer {
  background-color: #777;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: end;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="panel-1">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-content">
          <div class="panel-content-header">Panel Header</div>
          <div class="panel-content-scrollable">
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>

            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>

            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>

            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
            <div>Line Item</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <button>Change Panel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-2"></div>
    <div class="panel-3"></div>
    <div class="panel-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex` and `flex-basis: x%;` for your height values.

Because of `flex-direction: column;` flex-basis will calculate flex-child elements height values. I don't actually understand how are you going to calculate heights in your question but i think this will make you closer to solution.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.container{
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 10%;
}

.header p{
  color:white;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.scroll-panel p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.scroll-panel{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 80%;
}

button{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  flex-basis: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <p>HEADER</p>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-panel">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <button>Change</button>
</div>
```